# Bootstrap Carousel in Rails

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I'm working a project that has several images inside of a folder.  I've got Bootstrap working on my project, and was attempting to work in a carousel using [this tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_carousel.asp).  It seems to be an ideal fit for my needs, but I'm having trouble mixing it into my Ruby view.  Here's what I've got so far:

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <!-- Indicators -->
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <% @patient.images.each do |image| %>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <% end %>
  </ol>

  <!-- Wrapper for slides -->

      <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
       <div class="item active">
        <% @patient.images.each do |image| %>
        <%= image_tag image.image_file.url %>
        <% end %>
        </div>
      </div>


<!-- Left and right controls -->
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>
</div>
```

I think I've got a syntax/order issue where my divs and my image tags lie, but moving them around doesn't change anything.  What I'm trying to do is have a seperate slide for each image, but using the current code it seems to want to put all of the images in one slide.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how i did it:

```
<ol class="carousel-indicators">
   <% @patient.images.each_with_index do |photo, n| %>
     <li data-target='#MyCarousel' data-slide-to="#{n}" class="#{'active' if n == 0}"></li>
   <% end %>
</ol>

<div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
  <div class="item active">
    <%= image_tag @patient.images.first.image_file.url %>
  </div>
  <% @patient.images.drop(1).each do |photo| %>
     <div class="item">
       <%= image_tag photo.image_file.url %>
     </div>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

Comment: This is the answer I eventually ended up using more closely.  @Ren there are a few errors I was unable to edit due to it being less than 6 characters - a closing ruby tag on the second line, and the same on the 8th line

Comment: oops, i fixed those for you.  I had to convert that code from slim, hence the errors.  Glad my answer was useful!

Comment: No problem I caught them easily, just making note for those stumbling upon in the future.

Answer (score 14):

This part:

```
<ol class="carousel-indicators">
  <% @patient.images.each do |image| %>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
  <% end %>
</ol>
```

needs to be changed to something like:

```
<ol class="carousel-indicators">
  <% @patient.images.each_with_index do |image, index| %>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="<%= index %>" class="<%= index == 0 ? 'active' : '' %>"></li>
  <% end %>
</ol>
```

and this part:

```
<div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
 <div class="item active">
  <% @patient.images.each do |image| %>
    <%= image_tag image.image_file.url %>
  <% end %>
 </div>
</div>
```

needs to be like this:

```
<div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
  <% @patient.images.each_with_index do |image, index| %>     
    <div class="item <%= index == 0 ? 'active' : '' %>">
      <%= image_tag image.image_file.url %>
    <end>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

let me know if it works for you.

Comment: Intresting, I wasn't aware of the `each_with_index` function..  Tried your solution and getting an "expecting ')';" on the `<li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="<%= index %>" class="<%= index == 0 'active' : '' %>"></li>
` line

Comment: sorry, I was missing the ? in the ternary operator :), I updated the response.

Answer (score 0):

Updated for Bootstrap 5 and ActiveStorage images in Rails 6.  The answer below allows for adding multiple carousels to the same page by assigning each an id, it also removes the Bootstrap autoscroll by adding `data-bs-interval="false"`

```
  <div class="row">
    <% @properties.each do |property| %>
      <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-6 mb-3">

        <!-- carousel -->
        <div id="carousel_<%= property.id %>" class="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="carousel" data-bs-interval="false">
          <div class="carousel-inner">
            <% property.images.each_with_index do |image, index| %>
              <div id="carousel_item_<%= index %>" class="carousel-item <%= index == 0 ? 'active' : '' %>">
                <%= image_tag image.variant(resize_to_fit: [500,500]), class: 'd-block w-100' %><br>
              </div>
            <% end %>
          </div>
          <button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs-target="#carousel_<%= property.id %>" data-bs-slide="prev">
            <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
          </button>
          <button class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-bs-target="#carousel_<%= property.id %>" data-bs-slide="next">
            <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
          </button>
        </div>
     <% end %>
  </div>
```