# How to create a carousel photo gallery in Ruby On Rails

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to create a carousel as explained in "[Bootstrap Carousel in Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38357072/bootstrap-carousel-in-rails)" to no avail.

For each post I'll be loading a certain number of images which I'll like to to be displayed as a carousel in my show page.

My form.html.erb file is:

```
<div class="field">
  <%= form.label :images %>
  <%= form.file_field :images, multiple: true, class: 'form-control'%>
</div>
```

My post.rb file is:

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord
    has_many_attached :images
end
```

In my post_controller.rb file I have:

```
def post_params
    params.require(:post).permit(:titolo, :descrizione, images: [])
end
```

My show.html.erb file is:

```
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>

<div class='carousel-indicators<%= action_name%>_header'>
  <% (0...@post.images.count).each do |image| %>
      <%= image_tag(@post.images[image]) %>
  <% end %>
</div>

<p>
  <strong>Titolo:</strong>
  <%= @post.titolo %>
</p>
<p>
  <strong>Descrizione:</strong>
  <%= @post.descrizione %>
</p>
```

I would like my carousel to be exactly like [The Carousel Plugin](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_carousel.asp).

Comment: Bootstrap requires that you organize your HTML into hierarchy with specific classes. You are missing a bunch of that, and the `carousel-indicators` is the one only you use.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What does "to no avail" tell us? Please see "[ask]" and the linked pages and "[mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<!-- application.html.erb -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Rcar</title>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    <%= csp_meta_tag %>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <% @post = Post.first %>
    <div class="container">
      <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
          <% @post.images.each.with_index do |image, i| %>
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="<%= i %>" class="<%= 'active' if i == 0 %>"></li>
          <% end %>
        </ol>
        <div class="carousel-inner">
          <% @post.images.each.with_index do |image, i| %>
            <div class="item <%= 'active' if i == 0 %>">
              <%= image_tag(image, alt: SecureRandom.uuid) %>
              <div class="carousel-caption">
                <h3><%= SecureRandom.uuid %></h3>
                <p><%= SecureRandom.uuid %></p>
              </div>
            </div>           
          <% end %>
        </div>
        <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
          <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
        </a>
        <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
          <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <% if false %>
     <%= yield %>
    <% end %>
  </body>
</html>
```

```rb
# seeds.rb
# This file should contain all the record creation needed to seed the database with its default values.
# The data can then be loaded with the rails db:seed command (or created alongside the database with db:setup).
#
# Examples:
#
#   movies = Movie.create([{ name: 'Star Wars' }, { name: 'Lord of the Rings' }])
#   Character.create(name: 'Luke', movie: movies.first)

# Post.destroy_all

10.times do |t|
  Post.create!(
    titolo: SecureRandom.uuid,
    descrizione: SecureRandom.uuid,
    images: [
              '/home/foobar/upload_testing_files/25585110038_87fdc974b4_k.jpg',
              '/home/foobar/upload_testing_files/a9abe99a4b757585.jpg',
              '/home/foobar/upload_testing_files/27617329949_447f63140e_k.jpg'
            ].map { |path| Rack::Test::UploadedFile.new(path, 'image/jpg') }
  )
end
```

[image]